# Folder hierarchy in permalink

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo website, with a section `products`. The URL of products is configured to be `/p/:filename`. Actual product files are in subfolders of `content/products`.

Some products have the same file name, but they reside in different subfolders. I want to have URLs like:

- `content/products/shirts/very-beautiful-shirt.md` => `/p/shirts/very-beautiful-shirt`
- `content/products/shirts/simple.md` => `/p/shirts/simple`
- `content/products/hats/simple.md` => `/p/hats/simple`

Is there a way to have the subfolders showing up in the URL (permalink)? Of course, I'm aware I can specify the URL in every document, but I'd much rather have a better solution than that...

Answer (score 0):

your content structure outputs your URL structure.

So if you want /p/shorts/simple/
change your content folder /products/ to /p/
so /content/p/shorts/simple.md

will output to a url: /p/shorts/simple/

Then your URLs, unless you config is borked (separate issue), will display appropriately.

Let me know if that helps.

Their are ways to do global overrides and config shennanigans, but I would suggest at that point simply reading hugo docs, specifically "configuring hugo" in gohugo.io.

Comment: I do have a permalink structure override in the configuration, because I need localized permalinks (I mentioned `p` just for brevity, but it's actually `products`, `produits`, `prodotti`, etc.). The section "Configuring Hugo" is not helpful at all, as it never refers to subfolders; it briefly mentions a `:sections` value that only includes the top section (`products` in my case, without any subfolder).

Comment: https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#readout
I would suggest you use the standard hugo system for multilanguage (I'm working with 5 to 12 language sites) then you can use the standard hugo folder/file structures.

Comment: Is there no way to get the permalink configuration to do what I want? It seems a bit off to me that the "default" way works but if I want to customise the permalink then it stops working...

Comment: In your Hugo `config` file, what do you have set for `Permalinks.products`? If `products/`, `shirts/` and `hats/` each contain an `_index.md`, then something like this should work `products: /p/:sections[1]/:filename/`

Comment: I'm learning this myself and it might be that each source file under `products/`, e.g. `simple.md`, needs to be a leaf bundle, i.e. change `simple.md` to `simple/index.md` (in addition to what I wrote above). This seems like a bug but I'm not sure

Comment: I'm sorry, I could be totally misunderstanding, but if you want /products/
and for that to be different by language then make the folder /products/ or /제품/ whatever your base language is and use the multilingual (as in link) to handle the directories changing name. Which, from what I understand, is the permalink config you want.

Comment: Simone's question inspired me to learn a lot about URL paths in Hugo, which I wrote about in https://www.ii.com/hugo-urls/nested/sections/. My article includes instructions for doing what Simone asked for (and a lot of info about bundles, paths, sections, etc.) I was going to post here but it turned into a long article!